# Nexted optional route in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular8

Is there any way to do the nexted optional routing in Angular 8.

```
{
    path: 'mfa',//ConstantValues.route_list[0].route,
    data: { 'navBar': false },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'reset', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'mfa-code', component: MfaVerificationCodeComponent },
      { path: ':app', component: MfaMobileAppsComponent },
      { path: ':app/:provider', component: AppProviderComponent }
    ]
  }
```

I am focusing in these two lines

```
{ path: ':app', component: MfaMobileAppsComponent },
{ path: ':app/:provider', component: AppProviderComponent }
```

URL I am trying to achieved

```
https://localhost:44307/mfa/google/apple --> google and apple is optional
https://localhost:44307/mfa/okta/google  --> okta and google is optional
```

I don't want to use the query parameter because I have some other conditions. And how do I get the value of the url in TS file.

Comment: So what problem or issue that you faced now?

Comment: AppProviderComponent is not loaded keep loding MfaMobileAppsComponent

Answer (score 0):

To navigate I need to use and this works

```
 protected submit(model: MfaAppViewModel) {
    this.router.navigate(['{providerName}'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

Another Example

```
{path: 'studentList', component : StudentListComponent},  
{path: 'studentDetails/:id/:name/:marks', component : StudentDetailsComponent}


<a routerLink="/studentDetails/{{stud.id}}/{{stud.name}}/{{stud.marks}}"> Id : {{stud.id}}, Name : {{stud.name}} </a>
```

To read the value in TS file

```
 this.providerName = this.route.snapshot.params['provider'];
```